# Format specifier for C

Tags: c

I am trying to re-write something that's written in C++ to C.

```
double sclk_freq_mhz = (double)pLog->clk_freq / 1000L;
```

in the struct of pLog for which `clk_freq` is a member of, is of type `unsigned int` hence why it is being type casted to `double`. However, I noticed that there is an `L` at the end of 1000. What is this `L`? It appears to be of some kindof format specifier or length specifier which I am not familiar of.

if I want to write the above statement in C, what do I need to do? Do I write it like as follows or what?

```
double sclck_freq_mhz;
sprintf(sclck_freq_mhz,"%fL",pLog->clk_freq);
```

Thanks!

Comment: L stands for `Long` in both C and C++. Generally, 1000L is a `long` type constant

Answer (score 5):

`L` in `1000L` indicates this integer literal is of type `long`.

As to how to convert that C++ code to C, the answer is: it is already legal C code. Your code using `sprintf` doesn't make sense.